# Background image attribute not support in Microsoft office outlook 2007

Tags: html

```
                    //this is my Email Template HTML code
                    <center>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="650" style="margin:auto; border-spacing:0px;">
                    <tr>
                    <td height="177" width="650" background="http://dev.artoonsolutions.com/newsmtp/images/thankyou_email_top_bg.png" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td height="100" width="650" background="http://dev.artoonsolutions.com/newsmtp/images/thankyou_email_middle.png" style="background-repeat:repeat-y;" valign="baseline">
                    <div style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#666666; line-height:150%; width:494px; margin:auto; word-break:loose; display:block;">
                    <p style="text-align:right; margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0px;">May 26, 2 011</p>
                    <p style="text-align:left; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0px;">Dear {full name},</p>
                    <p style="text-align:left; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0px;">At CKR Interactive, we value relationships. Without them, we could not do what we do best and continue to provide our clients with extraordinary, and effective, recruitment solutions for their businesses. That is why we are sending you this note – to thank you for contacting us.</p>
                    <p style="text-align:left; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0px;">While we are confident that we can help you develop, plan, and follow through with unique and compelling recruitment strategies, we are 
                    primarily thrilled to have had the chance to meet with you about {subject}. </p>
                    <p style="text-align:left; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0px;">We look forward to having the opportunity to work closely in the future and would be very glad to bring you the results you have been seeking.</p>
                    <p style="text-align:left; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0px;">If theres anything you need, you can always reach us at <strong>866.527.4952</strong>  (Toll Free).</p>
                    <p style="text-align:left; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0px;">Here is to our mutual success! </p>
                    <p style="text-align:left; margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0px;">Yours truly,   </p>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td height="525" width="650"><img src="http://dev.artoonsolutions.com/newsmtp/images/thankyou_email_bottom.png" alt="img" width="650" height="525" border="0" usemap="#Map" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
background="..."
```

To:

```
style="background: url('...');"
```